# Stuck downgrading libssl on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have updated my `Ubtuntu 16.04` server earlier today, and one of my apps which uses `wkhtmltopdf` stopped working.

Based on the [thread here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3001), the solution is to downgrade and lock `libssl` to the previous version.

```
apt install libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8
```

When I try and downgrade:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/src$ sudo apt install libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8' for 'libssl-dev' was not found
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you received these down-votes. I'm imagining that StackOverflow is programming/computer-science related. In your case, you'd probably benefit more from https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @DawidLaszuk: Because it's not a programming question, it's a package management question. If neither the question nor an answer would benefit from showing source code, it's probably not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try different version of `libssl-dev`. According to other comment, and what [ubuntu has to offer](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libssl1.0.0), you might be better of with 4.10.

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10`

**Note**: For future reference in such specific questions please use respective StackExchange forum, like [Ask Ubuntu](https://www.askubuntu.com) or [Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi @DawidLaszuk, I have the same issue with your suggested version: `root@aubeta:/app# apt-get install libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10' for 'libssl-dev' was not found
root@aubeta:/app#`

Comment: @TheRealPapa could you please start new question on AskUbuntu and comment it here? In short check 1) check if you installed it `ldconfig -p | grep libssl`, and 2) check if you can install it `apt-cache search libssl`. I won't follow on this thread here as this is about programming.

Comment: Hi @DawidLaszuk thanks for the help. I added a question in AskUbuntu witht the output of the commands in your last comment. https://askubuntu.com/questions/989086/stuck-downgrading-libssl-on-ubuntu-16-04